# Wrong encoding in Windows Registry editor

Tags: windows, windows-registry, encoding

In the Windows registry editor, I noticed something strange. The path for the Inkscape executable is written in Japanese as you can see on this screenshot:

[image]

But this is not the case for Google Chrome or Filezilla for which the data is shown normally:

[image]

When I right click on one of the values for Inkscape which is written in Japanese and click on Change binary data, this is what I get:

[image]

So the data in the registry value is correct, it's only that the registry editor uses the wrong encoding to show what the value contains. What's strange is that it only does that for values in one key, not in the others. And when I move the same data from one key to another by copying/pasting the binary code, the encoding stays the same for each code (for example if I copy the binary code for Inkscape and paste it in the Filezilla key, it becomes written in Japanese in the Filezilla key too).

Why does the registry editor not use the right encoding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All strings in Windows (as well as in Windows *registry*) are supposedly in Unicode (simplification: each *character* = *two bytes*); I can reproduce your problem manually (registry value `TestValueCP1250`) although I can't imagine how-to do it programmatically:

```
==> reg query "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Test Key" /V TestValueCP1250

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Test Key
    TestValueCP1250    REG_SZ    㩃停潲牧浡䘠汩獥䍜浯潭⁮楆敬s
```

[image: TestValueCP1250]

Cf. the same data in Unicode (another registry value `TestValueUnicode`)

```
==> reg query "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Test Key" /V TestValueUnicode

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Test Key
    TestValueUnicode    REG_SZ    C:\Program Files\Common Files
```

[image: TestValueUnicode]

Comment: In a program you can decide whether to use the ANSI or the Unicode API, e.g., `RegSetValueExA` or `RegSetValueExW`, I imagine.